# Isomorphism between 2 vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

Can one vector space on $\mathbb{R}$ be isomorphic to a vector space on $\mathbb{C}$ if they have same dimension? (I was wondering about it while looking at $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ which are isomorphic, and thought of the right to expand the real vector space $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ on $\mathbb{C}$, it seemed for me natural to have a vector space on $\mathbb{C}$ for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ giving the fact that by exponentiation we get an element of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, defined just by complex matrices $2\times 2$ of determinant $1$). Does this question even have a sense?

Comment: I made a few changes, e.g. writing sl and so as $\mathfrak{sl}$ and $\mathfrak{so}$ respectively. I hope this is what you had in mind. Please change it back if it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you may say that a real vector space and a complex vector space are isomorphic *as real vector spaces*. You may also use the isomorphism to transport the structure of a complex vector space from one to the other. Depending on the context, you may not get the "most natural" complex structure, but as long as you are aware of what you're doing...

NB: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying with the complex structure of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$. It's the vector space of traceless $2 \times 2$ matrices with complex coefficients, so of course it is naturally a complex vector space. But maybe you mean that the Lie algebra of a complex Lie group is always a complex vector space thanks to exponentiation somehow, but it's simpler to say that it's a tangent space to a complex manifold.

Comment: There is something I'm missing. We say that so(3,1) and sl(2,C) are isomorphic because they have have same structure constants in their commutation relations. But so(3,1) is the 4x4 real matrices $\omega$ such that $\eta\omega$ is antisymetric (where $\eta$ is the Lorentz metric). Don't we bother if they are not defined on the same division ring ?

Comment: Why are you talking about a division ring? In any case, I think what you need to clarify is what "isomorphic" means when you say "$\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{so}(3, 1)$ are isomorphic". If you mean they are isomorphic as real vector spaces, no one cares about the Lie structure (by the way, there are more geometric ways to see that they are isomorphic as Lie algebras). Coming back to the complex structure, I don't think $so(3,1)$ has a natural complex structure in an obvious, direct manner.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it last night and realised that we make the isomorphism considering the real vector spaces (this is where we see that the constant structures are the same). Thanks for having help to make this clear.